# CORS not allowing jquery AJAX get results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am calling an AJAX function in my script from a server of IP  -  128.119.30.12:7080   (for example)

Cross Domain: port number are different, so I get error of incompatibility.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://128.119.30.12:9000/callback.php",
                data: dataObj,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                sucess: function(data,status){
                    reply = data;
                }, 
                error : function(xhr, status, error){
                    reply = {"error": "Error in fetching data"}
                }
            }).done(function(reply) {
                replyCall(reply);
            });

            function replyCall(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
```

I have enabled the mod_header function in my Apache server. And setting up header in the called php script - here is the script of php

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    print 'Hellooooooooo Response';
?>
```

It is still causing errors on chrome -
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://128.119.30.12:9000/callback.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://128.119.30.12:7080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: First fix your ajax you have a success and done callback?

Comment: Yes because I want to use the result to be submitted to the other function that called the ajax function.  Okay, let's ignore done function. It still has the same problem.

Comment: Look in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools. Look for the request to callback.php. Does it look like you expect? Is it the method you expect? Do you get the response you expect? Does the response include any errors? Does it include the Access Control headers?

Comment: Make sure you have [PHP error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) turned up as high as possible.

Comment: Request Header

`Host: 190.241.12.163:9204
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:38.0)
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://190.241.12.163:8070/node-app/test.html
Content-Length: 20
Origin: http://190.241.12.163:8070
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache`

Here is the Response header-
`Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 19 Jun 2015 07:21:45 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

Comment: Another information  port 9204 is running on NODEjs. I think that may be the main problem. We need to set header for nodeJS server instead of the Apache Server.

Comment: Guys, This problem is resolved. It was just to set header in the Node JS response instead of the PHP code.